# Trying to filter a key in a nested hash inside an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have the following array:

```
[#<PatchedOpenStruct name="Kristen Stewart", id="162655167", characters=["Snow White"]>, #<PatchedOpenStruct name="Chris Hemsworth", id="770829335", ch
aracters=["The Huntsman"]>, #<PatchedOpenStruct name="Charlize Theron", id="162654733", characters=["The Queen"]>, #<PatchedOpenStruct name="Viggo Mort
ensen", id="162654541">, #<PatchedOpenStruct name="Sam Claflin", id="771073196", characters=["Prince"]>]
```

i am trying to filter all the 'name' fields from this. any help?

Comment: filter meaning: a) show me all the names... or b) show me the PatchedOpenStruct that match a specific name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to extract all the names, use [`collect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-collect) (or its [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) alias) to call the `name` method on each element of the array and collect the results in another array:

```
names = a.collect(&:name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I can think of to do this if these were standard OpenStructs.

`array_of_things.collect{|each_thing| each_thing.name}` returns an array of all the names of all the things.
`array_of_things.select{|each_thing| each_thing.name =~ /Kristen/}` returns an array of things with names that match the expression `/Kristen/`.